# Hide/Show animation

Tags: gwt, panel

I would like to know if it is possible to make an animation on hide/show panel with simple gwt (without additonnal librairies).

Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

GWT's Layout classes support animation. Check out `Layout`, `DockLayout` en `SplitLayout`. Furthermore, there is an `Animation` class, which is used in several panels for using animation to show/hide the content. Simply check the classes using the Animation class.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you will find this code useful from [NotificationMole](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/NotificationMole.html):

```
private class MoleAnimation extends Animation {
    private int endSize;
    private int startSize;

    @Override
    protected void onComplete() {
      if (endSize == 0) {
        borderElement.getStyle().setDisplay(Display.NONE);
        return;
      }
      borderElement.getStyle().setHeight(endSize, Unit.PX);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onUpdate(double progress) {
      double delta = (endSize - startSize) * progress;
      double newSize = startSize + delta;
      borderElement.getStyle().setHeight(newSize, Unit.PX);
    }

    void animateMole(int startSize, int endSize, int duration) {
      this.startSize = startSize;
      this.endSize = endSize;
      if (duration == 0) {
        onComplete();
        return;
      }
      run(duration);
    }
  }
```

**Usage:**

- to hide panel:

  animation.animateMole(heightMeasure.getOffsetHeight(), 0,
            animationDuration);
- to show:

  borderElement.getStyle().setDisplay(Display.BLOCK);
  animation.animateMole(0, heightMeasure.getOffsetHeight(), animationDuration);

Where `borderElement` - container DivElement and `heightMeasure` - inner DivElement.